# Display date in format of YYYY-MM-DD in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Display the date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD. Explain to me with one simple program.

Comment: Hint:  `FORMAT()`.  `CONVERT()`.

Comment: Worry about the format in the presentation later; stick to the Date and Time data types in SQL which don't have a format. I don't recommend `FORMAT` though; it's known to be slow. `CONVERT` is a better option, but the presentation later is still the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. For different types of date formats to be displayed, you can get help from this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/).

Another way is to `Convert()` function as shown in the link [Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)
.

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as DateWithFormat
```

The output here will be

```
DateWithFormat
--------------
2020-02-15
```

Here is the official documentation of [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
.